# How to stop the keypress even listener when I am type in a form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am try to change the visibility state of a specific div when the user press "s" or any specific key. Below code works just fine however, it toggles the visibility state even when I am typing something in the form or input field. Any suggestions on how I can write a exception or something to stop the function from executing when user is type in a form.

And also how do I toggle the visibility state from visible to hidden when the user press the same key again?

```js
var searchBar = document.querySelector(".search-pop-up");

document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  toggleSearchBar(event.key);
});

function toggleSearchBar(key) {
  if (key === "s") {
    searchBar.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance. Have a good day!

Comment: Do you want to add the eventlistener on the `document`?

Comment: The solution depends on the HTML structure of the page. One way is to check, whether `event.target` has `form` property (in the keypress listener, which, by the way, you should change to keydown listener, as keypress is deprecated). If you have content editable elements other than form control elements, things will get more complicated.

Comment: The key concepts here are "event propagation" and "event bubbling." For instance, when you click a `button` inside a `card` inside a `sidebar` inside `main` inside `body`, the click event can and will be captured through those elements by tricking down and bubbling up (See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/7216508). As part of your event handler function, you might want to check whether the `event.currentTarget` is the intended `input` field to conditionally ignore the keyboard event.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to toggle visibility based on element's previous value. You can make sue that if your input is the active element, then shouldn't toggle visibility:

```js
var searchBar = document.querySelector(".search-pop-up");

document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  toggleSearchBar(event.key);
});

function toggleSearchBar(key) {
  if (document.activeElement != searchBar && key === "s") {
    searchBar.style.visibility = searchBar.style.visibility === "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
  }
}
```

```css
.search-pop-up {
  visibility: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input class="search-pop-up" />
<button>My button</button>
```

Comment: I am just one day old when it comes to JavaScript. However, your suggestion gave me an idea of how I can approach it. Thank you so much 
Check the submitted answer for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the keydown;

Alternatively, you can return false to stop events propagation

```
  function onsubmit(event) {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short brief about the solution. First, get the active element tagName and then check if it is equal to or not equal to any specific tagName and then execute the function below.

To toggle the visibility I set an if statement to check specific values for example "visible" if it is visible then the next line of code will change it to "hidden" and vice versa.

```js
var searchBar = document.querySelector(".search-pop-up");

document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  // Captures the current active element tagName
  var currentElement = document.activeElement.tagName;
  var currentElementLower = currentElement.toLowerCase();
  // Checks if the current active not equal to "input"
  if (currentElementLower != "input") {
    toogleSearchBar(event.key);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

// Toogle the visibility state
function toogleSearchBar(key) {
  if (key === "s") {
    if (searchBar.style.visibility === "visible") {
      searchBar.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
      searchBar.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps someone new to JavaScript.

Comment: FYI, when listening a KeyboardEvent on `document`, `event.target` is always `document.body` if the target element is not specifically an element which can gain focus (like a content editable or a form control element). You can simply check the target in `keydown` listener, and call the toggler only if the target is `document.body`.